# not found in solana validators, however, found in solana gossip

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, validator, solana-test-validator

I've been running a Solana validator, and I've noticed that my validator is not showing up when I run the 'solana validators' command. However, the 'solana gossip' command shows my validator as active.

I started the validator for about 4.5 hours, but there was no change.
Looking at the validator and system logs, I don't see any errors.

Here are some details:

- Network: testnet
- Command used:

  - found : solana gossip
  - not found : solana validators

Am I missing any specific steps or configurations? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

hikari

Comment: Additionally, the command below seems to work.
solana catchup <keypair> The execution machine is running on Google Cloud Platform. The situation is the same for devnet, testnet, and mainnet. It's been stuck here for weeks,I'm very confused and don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated!